# OpenCV python module build error

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to build opencv 3 from source(I'm using VS 2013 and compiling for 32bit) so that I can play with feature detection stuff in OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES with python. My python version is 2.7.5. Everything builds fine except pyopencv_generated. Here's the error log from visual studio. I'm getting vector_Rect2d and boundingBox undeclared identifier errors. VS reports 23 errors in total. All of them can be seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Here's the relevant CMAKE screenshot.

[image]

Everything else seems to be working OK except this and this is the part that I need unfortunately. Any suggestions? What should I do?

Comment: Error #2 tells you it can't find the lib. All the other errors are caused by not knowing about things inside those libs. Check your linkers paths and maybe start with static paths

Comment: try to update your opencv3 repo. `vector<Rect2d>` and friends were recently added to the python bindings (to make tracking work), and it seems you don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to berak's comment I was able to fix the issue. It appears that there is some kind of discrepancy between contrib part of the opencv and the installation file provided by opencv. Python enabled build always fails when both of them combined. So I pulled opencv from github rather than using the provided download file.

In short if you are having trouble, pull everything from github rather than using the opencv_download.exe from the opencv.org